# Python: customized YAML dumping format

Tags: python, yaml

I'm using PyYAML 3.12 for parsing and dumping YAML files. In a special case, I have to dump a string which can be used in config files.

```
config: "# something like this"
```

By default, PyYAML dumps it like this:

```
config: # something like this
```

it obviously doesn't work because it essentially removes it. I tried to do `follow_style='"'`. It appears to be working but the output is butchered into something that cannot be read by human.

Is there a way to do this nicely? A hook or something that dumps all string with quotes?

ps. I am aware (only from a few minutes ago) of the existence of `ruamel.yaml` but not sure if it fits my needs. Plus PyYAML has been working fine otherwise for a while now.

Comment: Please give a [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). PyYAML does quote it properly when I do `yaml.dump({"config": "# something like this"})`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. By doing so I discovered that the code I'm modifying has `replace('\'', '')` after the `dump()` :(. Possibly it was using an older version of PyYAML.

Comment: @lang2 This should work in PyYAML. Every change has its danger, so until there is a real need you can stay with PyYAML. ruamel.yaml supports YAML 1.2 and has many bugs that are still in PyYAML fixed. But through its extra functionality, ruamel.yaml might of course have new issues, not existent in PyYAML. I test every change in ruamel.yaml against the PyYAML test suite as well as a bunch of extra tests, but that is no guarantee for backwards compatibility.